# Naming variables according to rows in R

Tags: r

I have to data tables. Data table 1 has two variables and 561 observations while data table 2 has 563 variables and 10,000 observations. I'm trying to figure out how can I the observations of `code_name` variable from data table 1 to rename the variables in data table 2.

**What I have:**

Data table 1

```
code   code_name 
11      rasf
04      iadf
27      pqwr
09      pklf
86      irmw
30      pwql
```

Data table 2

```
activity    subject     V1      V2      V3      V4    V5     V6 
   5            2       0.29    0.19    5.3     1.8    8.3   0.3
   9            7       0.11    0.10    7.8     2.0    0.5   0.9
   9            7       0.19    1.10    8.0     1.9    0.4   0.7
```

**What I need:**

```
activity    subject    rasf    iadf    pqwr    pklf   irmw  pwql 
   5            2       0.29    0.19    5.3     1.8    8.3   0.3
   9            7       0.11    0.10    7.8     2.0    0.5   0.9
   9            7       0.19    1.10    8.0     1.9    0.4   0.7
```

**What I did:**

```
#Extracts all rows and just column two from the data table 1

new_data_table1 <- data_table1[,2]

#Set names on data table 2 to build the final data

final_data <- setnames(data_table2, names(data_table2), c("activity", "subject", new_data_table1))
```

The problem with my code is that when I extract all rows from data table 1 it gives a long list, showing vectors for the structure and labels of the data. Because of that, when I run my code I get this table:

```
activity   subject      243     244     245     246    247   248 
   5            2       0.29    0.19    5.3     1.8    8.3   0.3
   9            7       0.11    0.10    7.8     2.0    0.5   0.9
   9            7       0.19    1.10    8.0     1.9    0.4   0.7
```

The new names for the variables are numbers because they are the structures and not the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to find the index of the column names in the second dataset that start with "V" followed by numbers and change it to the second column value from the first dataset.

```
names(df2)[grep("^V\\d+", names(df2))] <- as.character(df1[,2] )
```

Comment: This answer could be risky in that the indices returned by `grep` are blindly being used to replace the names in `df2` by those in `df1`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I guess the OP's columns are in order.  Assuming that the number of elements are the same in both the datasets, the `grep` will give the index of the columns in 'df2' even if there are other columns in between.  But, here the assumption is that the `V` columns are numbered ascendingly.

Comment: That's right! The `V` columns of my dataset are in order and numbered in an ascending way.

Answer (score 3):

we can use names function to naming variables according to rows

```
names(df1)[3:length(df1)] <- df$code_name


df1
  activity subject rasf iadf pqwr pklf irmw pwql
1        5       2 0.29 0.19  5.3  1.8  8.3  0.3
2        9       7 0.11 0.10  7.8  2.0  0.5  0.9
3        9       7 0.19 1.10  8.0  1.9  0.4  0.7
```

## data

```
df
  code code_name
1   11      rasf
2    4      iadf
3   27      pqwr
4    9      pklf
5   86      irmw
6   30      pwql


 df1
  activity subject   V1   V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
1        5       2 0.29 0.19 5.3 1.8 8.3 0.3
2        9       7 0.11 0.10 7.8 2.0 0.5 0.9
3        9       7 0.19 1.10 8.0 1.9 0.4 0.7
```